# Realtime UI and LiveCharts update in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, livecharts

I'm trying to implement a real-time plot UI, i'm using WPF with the MVVM Pattern and Live-Charts by beto-rodriguez as my plot library, but i have some trouble with updating the graphs in real time. I know that i have to run multiple threads to update the UI in realtime, but every single way i tried doesn't work (i'm learning C# now).
I'm confused of how i should properly implement this pattern for the realtime update, and if the plot library is able to do that.

This is my actual code (its a simplified version of what i will do and doesn't implement any multithread code)

ModelView Code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using LiveCharts;


    namespace TestMotionDetection
    {
        class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public SeriesCollection Series { get; set; }

            public Func<double, string> YFormatter { get; set; }
            public Func<double, string> XFormatter { get; set; }

            public DataViewModel SData
            {
                set
                {
                    Series[0].Values.Add(value);
                    OnPropertyChanged("Series");
                }
            }

            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            public MainViewModel()
            {
                SeriesConfiguration<DataViewModel> config = new SeriesConfiguration<DataViewModel>();
                config.Y(model => model.Value);
                config.X(model => model.Time);

                Series = new SeriesCollection(config)
                {
                    new LineSeries {Values = new ChartValues<DataViewModel>(), PointRadius = 0}
                };

                XFormatter = val => Math.Round(val) + " ms";
                YFormatter = val => Math.Round(val) + " °";
            }

            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

            public void generateData()
            {
                DataViewModel val = new DataViewModel();
                for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
                {
                    val.Time = i;
                    val.Value = i + 2.3f;
                    SData = val;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the View code:

```
using System.Windows;


namespace TestMotionDetection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logica di interazione per MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private MainViewModel vista;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            vista = new MainViewModel();
            DataContext = vista;
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            vista.generateData();
        }
    }
}
```

And the XALM:

```
<Window x:Class="TestMotionDetection.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts;assembly=LiveCharts"
        Title="Example 2  (WPF)"
        Width="1025.213"
        Height="482.801">

    <Grid>
        <lvc:LineChart Margin="0,2,245,-2"
                       LegendLocation="Right"
                       Series="{Binding Series}">
            <lvc:LineChart.AxisX>
                <lvc:Axis LabelFormatter="{Binding XFormatter}" Separator="{x:Static lvc:DefaultAxes.CleanSeparator}" />
            </lvc:LineChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:LineChart.AxisY>
                <lvc:Axis LabelFormatter="{Binding YFormatter}" />
            </lvc:LineChart.AxisY>
        </lvc:LineChart>
        <Button x:Name="button"
                Width="151"
                Height="79"
                Margin="804,47,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Click="button_Click"
                Content="Button" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[UPDATE 1]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26bdk.jpg)

Comment: you don't need multi threading for live charts to work, please if you are having an issue conciser reporting it to the gitbug repo https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts

Answer (score 1):

Your XFormatter & YFormatter should both be like this:

```
private Func<double, string> _yFormatter;
public Func<double, string> YFormatter { 
    get{ return _yFormatter; }
    set
    {
        _yFormatter = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("YFormatter");
    }
```

If you are using C#6 you should do `nameof(YFormatter)` instead.

That will cause the view to update, otherwise the view has no way of knowing that the formatter changed.

Comment: The problem is not the formatter, in my "main" implementation the plot updates a second after the stream of data ends, without me changing the formatter values. I only insert new datas in the Series.

Comment: If your formatters never change than the issue is probably related to Live-Charts... of part of the code that you haven't placed here. Everything else looks fine from an MVVM standpoint. I would recommend you add Live-Charts to you tags and/or place this question on their forums.

Comment: ... Or you need to call `OnPropertyChanged("YFormatter");` every time you add an item to the series.

Comment: I updated the post with the output of my "main" implementation.
I don't post it because it's garbage code that i need to fix.

You can see that the Formatters (labels) are updated.
I think it's  a thread problem

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding what the problem is. Can you clarify what results you are expecting and what you are getting?

Comment: The plot updates only when the stream of data ends. It must be in real time when a value it's added to the Series (from 50 to 200 Hz). Now i'm trying to achieve this by starting from a simplified version of my program, so I can understand what i have to do.

Comment: Whenever the data changes you need to call `OnPropertyChanged("YFormatter");` & `OnPropertyChanged("YFormatter");` So you either need to into that property's changed/updated event or create your own.

Comment: The problem is not with the Formatter, i need to implement multithreading, but i don't understand where and in which way.